# c# pass selected items from listbox to another form

Tags: c#, listbox

I have Listbox1 with multiple selection mod. Now i want, when items in that Listbox are selected to pass them on next form. Listbox is on form1, when clicked next to form2 to show me in label on form2 what items are selected in Listbox form1.

tried this

```
foreach (var item in listBoxSobe.SelectedItems)
{
   lblSobe.Text += (lblSobe.Text == "" ? "" : ", ") + item.ToString();
}
```

but as result i get "System.Data.DataRowView.." , and not clicked items from Listbox

Comment: because you are passing the object and not the value.   try adding strItem = item.ToString();  and pass strItem to the lblSobe.text instead of item

Comment: @Brian it's because item is of type `DataRowView`, not because of passing object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
foreach (DataRowView item in listBoxSobe.SelectedItems)
{
   lblSobe.Text += (lblSobe.Text == "" ? "" : ", ") + item["TheColumnYouWant"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Sorry i'm new 
If That is "Was this post useful to you?" i clicked Yes :p

Comment: If you see beside the arrow up and down there is a V. If you click on that it means that you accept this answer as the solution to question :-)